# Is there a way to get the config for a dynamically loaded behavior in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: cakephp-2.6

Example:

```
$Model->Behaviors->load('Some.Behaviour', $options);

// Now how do I get $options back from the model?
```

Is there a way to get `$options`? `$Model->actsAs` remains empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those options are stored in the `settings` property of the Behavior itself. You can get to it by using:

```php
$this->Behaviors->Behavior->settings[''];
```

For example:

```php
$this->Behaviors->load('Containable', array('hello' => 'world'));
var_dump($this->Behaviors->Containable->settings);
```

Would return:

```
array (size=2)
  'priority' => int 10
  '' => 
    array (size=4)
      'recursive' => boolean true
      'notices' => boolean true
      'autoFields' => boolean true
      'hello' => string 'world' (length=5)
```

As you can see, the "hello world option" is right there at the bottom.